# Replace AAA for BBB in file

Tags: replace

Given I have a file with several words, how can I do the following:

How can I replace AAA for BBB in a file with Unix?

Comment: `sed -i.bak 's/AAA/BBB/g'`

Comment: I downvoted the question, because it didn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed s/AAA/BBB/g input.txt > output.txt
```

You can then check output.txt and copy it over input.txt. Learn [more about sed here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).